# running applications over graphic card

Tags: c++, linux, gpgpu

I'm developing on C++ under Ubuntu. My application has a lot of threads (more than 25).

My question is:

1. If I will run my app on the graphic card (which is known as CPU with lot of cores), will I see an improvement in the performance?
2. I know that graphic cards have more cores than I7 (for example), so my app will has less context switches and thus better performance, is that true?
3. Do the cores of the graphic cards (in the basic) have a better performance than the CPU cores? I know that it depends on the graphic card and CPU type, but is there a general answer?

Comment: See [Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs](http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus) on SuperUser.

Comment: You might consider [opencl](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) but it is difficult, and is not a silver bullet.

Comment: Perhaps CUDA - http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html

Answer (score 0):

1. That depends on the type of parallelism you have in your application. If you have task parallelism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_parallelism), each thread is doing a different task (i.e. one thread is doing networking, another is doing computation, rendering etc.).
   This type of parallelism is not adequate with the GPU, as the GPU is a data parallel machine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism). It is very efficient if you need to perform the same computation on many data items. For instance many image processing algorithms falls into this category, as the same computation is done on every image pixel (image filtering etc.). From my experience on these kind of computations you can achieve around x50 speedup and even higher. (Comparing high end CPU's vs high end GPU's)
2. It is true if you're application is computation bound and the computation is data parallel (see 1.)
3. Usually GPU cores work with lower ( < 1 GHz ) clock rate than CPU cores so you might say that each CPU core (generally speaking) has higher performance than each GPU core. Thing is modern GPUs have thousands of cores.